# Why doesn't NetBeans recognize Django syntax?

Tags: python, django, netbeans, ide

I installed the 3 python plugins from tools >> plugins >> available plugins >> search "python" and then restarted Netbeans. Yet when I open a file with the following content:

```
{% block foo %}

   // hi

{% endblock %}
```

putting my cursor on the opening block tag does not cause the ending block tag to be highlighted. This works for other languages like PHP brace matching or HTML tag matching, how can I get this syntax recognition to work for Django. I want the same type of closing tag matching/code hinting/error alerts.

I tried changing the template extension from .html to .djt and .dj to try to get Netbans to recognize the file as a django template but no luck.

Answer (score 4):

Can't leave this unanswered... Because Python != Django

Django is a framework, and it does not comes with python, so netbeans doesn't supports Django template syntax by default, this is normal.